# End of input in XTerm usnig keyboard

Tags: xterm, c++

How can I signal XTerm terminal to end of input. In my case, I run a C++ program in XTerm console and I want to signal the program the end of input by pressing some combination of keyboard buttons.(I tried Ctrl+D Ctrl+Z ).My program goes like this :

```
map<int,string>info;
string name;
int age;
cin>>name;
while( **?????????** ){   //Input till EOF , missing logic
    cin>>age;
    info.insert( pair<int,string>(age,name) );
    cin>>name;
}
```

The program proceeds upon receiving the end of input signal from terminal.

Comment: Hum. How about questioning cin.eof()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **always** need to check the input **after** reading, i.e., your program should look something like this:

```
while (std::cin >> name >> age) {
    // do something with name and age
}
```

This will read from `std::cin` until something fails. You can check if `std::cin.eof()` is set to determine if having reached the end of the of the input is the cause of the error or there was some other failure, e.g., an attempt to enter something which isn't a number for the `age`.